# Return from root to user using python os.system('kill') not working

Tags: python, root, exit, os.system

I need to run a command from my python script as a root user (just sudo wont work), so I use os.system('sudo su') and am able to get root access. But again I need to return back to user . I tried os.system('exit'), but it still doesnt come out of root login to user login. I have to manually enter exit in the terminal to get back to user login. Can someone help me on how to do this in python ?

```
import os
import time
os.system('clear') #clear the terminal
os.system('sudo eject /dev/sr0')
time.sleep(2)
os.system('sudo modprobe option')
time.sleep(2)
os.system('sudo su')
time.sleep(5)
os.system('echo 2001 7d0e > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id')
time.sleep(2)
os.system('exit')
```

Comment: You can use `sudo bash -c "command > file"` to run a single command with output redirect as root. This is easy to make into a function

Comment: @slezica I dont quite understand this. If you dont mind can you please show me an example on how to do this in the python script above ?

Comment: left an example below :)

Comment: Oups! Each and every `os.system` starts a different shell, so `echo 2001 7d0e > /sys...` will **not** be executed as a super user, and `os.system('exit')` is a noop: you start a subshell that immediately exits...

Answer (score 0):

Your `echo` command doesn't work with `sudo` because the redirection to `> /sys/bus/...` is made by your own user, and then given to `sudo echo`, but root is required to access the file in the 1st place.

Try using `sudo bash -c 'command > redirect'` instead, which will acquire root permissions *before* attempting the redirect:

```
def sudo(command):
  return os.system("sudo bash -c '{}'".format(command))

sudo('echo foo > /sys/restricted/file')
```